# Controlling keyboard LEDs with USB Host Shield

Tags: c++, usb, keyboard

I've got a USB keyboard connected to my Arduino Uno with a USB Host Shield. I'm reading keystrokes using [this example](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/examples/HID/USBHIDBootKbd/USBHIDBootKbd.ino) from the USB Host Shield library.

I need to toggle the LEDs in the keyboard (that indicate the state of Caps Lock, Num Lock etc.)

[This thread](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=300560.0) mentions using `Usb.setReport()`, but this method doesn't seem to exist any more: there's no such method in [Usb.cpp](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/Usb.cpp) in the library. There does seem to be [a method](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/06d5ed134a37e22575c0ce18c061d9ef115151e0/usbhid.h#L185) called `SetReport` in the USBHID class, which looks like it takes the same arguments, which I'm trying to use.

What I'm currently doing:

```
void keyboard_setup(){
    static HIDBoot<USB_HID_PROTOCOL_KEYBOARD> HidKeyboard(&Usb);
    if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
        Serial.println("OSC did not start.");
    }
    delay(200);
    HidKeyboard.SetReportParser(0, &Prs);

    static USBHID usbhid(&Usb);
    uint8_t leds = 1;
#define KBD_ADDR 1
#define KBD_IF 0
    usbhid.SetReport( KBD_ADDR, 0, 1, KBD_IF, 0, &leds );
    delay(100);
    leds = 255;
    usbhid.SetReport( KBD_ADDR, 0, 1, KBD_IF, 0, &leds );
    delay(100);
```

Neither call to SetReport seems to work, and I'm not certain the values of KBD_ADDR or KBD_IF are correct (I'm using ones that I've seen in examples), or event that calling SetReport is right .

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I posted an answer but deleted it.  My 1st thought was that you were creating your own instance of the SetReport method (which you are) that didn't work w/any USB device.  But looking at your code again - I'm not so sure.

Comment: @st2000 I'm creating my own instance of USBHID, which I don't otherwise use, because I seem to need it to use SetReport(). I'm not sure if that's the right approach though.

Comment: This is going to take a bit of thinking for me.  But I think the best way to go about controlling the keyboard LEDs is to expose SetReport to your Sketch by adding a wrapper method to the USBHost library.  Otherwise, I'm thinking you need to setup all the USB stuff in your Sketch - which the driver already is capable of doing.

Comment: I thought [NicoHood/HID](https://github.com/NicoHood/HID/tree/master/src/HID-APIs) github page was the answer, but I think it works with custom keyboard and does not necessary work w/standard USB keyboard LEDs.

Comment: the NicoHood/HID uses an Arduino to emulate a keyboard .... there is no actual keyboard involved

Answer (score 2):

> There does seem to be [a method](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/06d5ed134a37e22575c0ce18c061d9ef115151e0/usbhid.h#L185) called `SetReport` in the USBHID class, which looks like it takes the same arguments, which I'm trying to use.

The method arguments of the new `SetReport()` method aren't quite the same and some are in a different order.

The old method signature was:

```
uint8_t setReport( uint8_t addr, uint8_t ep, unsigned int nbytes, uint8_t interface, uint8_t report_type, uint8_t report_id, uint8_t* dataptr );
```

...while the new one is:

```
uint8_t SetReport(uint8_t ep, uint8_t iface, uint8_t report_type, uint8_t report_id, uint16_t nbytes, uint8_t* dataptr);
```

It seems to me the equivalent call would be:

```
usbhid.SetReport( 0, KBD_IF, 0x02, 0, 1, &leds );
```